# Не выполняется код в сокращенной версии тега PHP

Tags: php

Обновил сервер и теперь код обернутый в `<? ?>` перестал выполняться. Как подправить?

Попутно - вообще насколько правильно так писать, стоит ли избегать такого сокращения?

Сейчас в php.ini стоит

```
; short_open_tag
;   Default Value: On
;   Development Value: Off
;   Production Value: Off
```

Что выставить? И что значит каждая категория?

Comment: Какая версия php ?

Comment: В файле php.ini нужно включить сокращенные теги

Comment: 5.6 версия версия

Comment: Все эти строки закомментированы, ищите ниже, без точки с запятой

Comment: выставил, перезапустил, но все равно не работает

Comment: Нашел)) Спасибо за совет

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Параметр в файле php.ini, отвечающий за распознавание коротких тэгов называется  Short_open_tag. Его нужно установить в значение On:

```
short_open_tag = On
```

Answer (score 1):

Когда PHP обрабатывает файл, он ищет открывающие и закрывающие теги, такие как `<?php и ?>`, которые указывают PHP, когда начинать и заканчивать обработку кода между ними. Подобный способ обработки позволяет PHP внедряться во все виды различных документов, так как всё, что находится вне пары открывающих и закрывающих тегов, будет проигнорировано парсером PHP.

PHP также допускает короткий открывающий тег `<?`, однако использовать их нежелательно, так как они доступны только если включены с помощью конфигурационной директивы `php.ini short_open_tag` (Установить в **On**), либо если PHP был сконфигурирован с опцией `--enable-short-tags` .

Если файл содержит только код PHP, предпочтительно опустить закрывающий тег в конце файла. Это помогает избежать добавления случайных символов пробела или перевода строки после закрывающего тега PHP, которые могут послужить причиной нежелательных эффектов, так как PHP начинает выводить данные в буфер при отсутствии намерения у программиста выводить какие-либо данные в этой точке скрипта.

> php 7.0.0 - ASP теги <%, %>, <%=, и теги скриптов  удалены из PHP.

Для поздних версий

> 5.4.0 Тег `<?=` доступен всегда, вне зависимости от настройки short_open_tag.

Источник: [php.net](http://php.net/manual/ru/language.basic-syntax.phptags.php)

Comment: short_open_tag
;   Default Value: On
;   Development Value: Off
;   Production Value: Off

Comment: Сейчас там такая картина